# install scipy on windows with easy_install

Tags: python, windows-7, easy-install

I installed python 2.7 64bit on Windows 7. I later realized that my windows is 32 bit...

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:24) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win
32
```

Anyway, it is still working! I also added the python installation directory in the windows path.

Than i installed easy_install using ez_setup script. And this worked, as well

```
C:\Users\Myname>easy_install
error: No urls, filenames, or requirements specified (see --help)
```

But then I am not able to install modules as Matplolib or Scipy!

```
C:\Users\Massimo\Dropbox\Python>easy_install scipy
Searching for scipy
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/
Best match: scipy 0.13.2
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.13.2.zip#md5
=9befa30e546fba762a0c1695a509f731
Processing scipy-0.13.2.zip
Writing c:\users\massimo\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-v3knvt\scipy-0.13.2\set
up.cfg
Running scipy-0.13.2\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\massimo\appdata\l
ocal\temp\easy_install-v3knvt\scipy-0.13.2\egg-dist-tmp-tatxbl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\scripts\easy_install-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.8', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1992
, in main
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1979
, in with_ei_usage
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1996
, in <lambda>
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 380,
 in run
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 623,
 in easy_install
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 653,
 in install_item
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 849,
 in install_eggs
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1130
, in build_and_install
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1115
, in run_setup
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 69, in run_setup
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 120, in run
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 71, in <lambda>
  File "setup.py", line 230, in <module>
  File "setup.py", line 218, in setup_package
ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Christoph Gohlke provides pre-built Windows installers [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy) including scipy.  Your best bet is to use one of them, the reason being that installing scipy, numpy & matplotlib from source requires building both C and Fortran extensions which most Windows machines do not have the compiler for.

Alternatively there are a number of pre-build istallations that include python and some other tools:

- [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads.html): A free distribution
  for the SciPy stack. Supports Linux, Windows and Mac.
- [Enthought Canopy](http://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/): The free and
  commercial versions include the core SciPy stack packages. Supports Linux,
  Windows and Mac.
- [Python(x,y)](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/): A free distribution
  including the SciPy stack, based around the Spyder IDE. Windows only.
- [WinPython](http://code.google.com/p/winpython/): A free distribution
  including the SciPy stack. Windows only.
- [Pyzo](http://www.pyzo.org/): A free distribution based on Python 3 with the IEP editor. Supports Linux and Windows.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sounds interesting. I would like to know if it is possible to use easy_install (or another package manager) as I already use python mainly in GNU/linux and it often happens that I need new packages.

Comment: If you are on Linux then `easy-install` works OK but `pip` generally works better and sometimes I have found `apt-get install` was the way to go - a few packages that weren't in the repositories I just downloaded the tar and unpacked, (or pulled with hg or git in some cases), and then `python setup.py install` in the resulting directory.  It is Windows that is the issue as most people can't build extension modules - on Windows I most often end up looking for a pre-built installer.

Comment: I think the best way is Anaconda, which has 400 python data science packages such as scipy, numpy, pandas