# Unable to install Scipy in windows?

Tags: python, windows, numpy, scipy

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xpL6.jpg)When I am installing Scipy using 
`pip install scipy` I am getting this error as shown in Image.
I've tried this many time and also I've tried `scikit-learn` but it also requires this Scipy. Please help me, I've to submit Project tomorrow. :(

**ERROR**

> Command ""c:\users\siraj munir\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\SIRAJM~1\AppData\Local\Temp‌​\pip-build-7mua6674‌​\scipy\setup.py';f‌​=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\SIRAJM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-0x99qqd0-record\ins‌​tall-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\SIRAJM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-7mua6674\scip‌​y\

Comment: what's your error?

Comment: Command ""c:\users\siraj munir\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\SIRAJM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-7mua6674\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\SIRAJM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-0x99qqd0-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\SIRAJM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-7mua6674\scipy\

Comment: Getting this is cmd.

Comment: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xpL6.jpg) screenshot in this link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [install scipy on windows with easy\_install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583380/install-scipy-on-windows-with-easy-install)

Comment: [This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39814710/2992902) resolved my issue in Windows 10 using Powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing scipy from here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

You'll need to know your version of python to choose correctly (I see you have 3.6). Also you'll need to know if it is 32 or 64 bits. You can do it by trial and error ;) or you can check the output of `python.exe`:

Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 **32 bit** (Intel)] on win32

The bold part indicates which version it is (don't get mislead by `win32` part).

Another option is to install anaconda. It is much heavier but you don't need to know anything.

Comment: I've also tried this but how to Run that Wheel file then?

Comment: @Siraj Munir `pip install scipy‑0.19.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl`

Comment: I have that page bookmarked for reasons such as this

Comment: Run cmd.exe in the directory where you've downloaded the whl file and enter `pip install scipy‑0.19.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl` there. Push Enter.

Comment: **C:\Users\Siraj Munir\Desktop>pip install scipy-0.19.0.whl
Requirement 'scipy-0.19.0.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
scipy-0.19.0.whl is not a valid wheel filename.**

Comment: My file exist in Desktop directory with the name given above in error comment!

Comment: It sounds silly, but renames are not allowed for whl files. Even `(1)` that Chrome adds to the filename if it already exists is disastrous for pip. Did you manage to install it?