# Scipy not installing in windows machine

Tags: python, windows, scipy, pip, pycharm

I was trying to install Scipy on Pycharm via Project Interpretor. Then it showed an error saying I should try typing `pip install scipy` on cmd. I did that and got the following error. It is still showing that it is not installed.

```
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-0.19.0.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scipy ... error
  Complete output from command d:\softwares\python3.6.1\python.exe -u -c "import
 setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-b
uild-k8_u1d9i\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code
=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))"
 bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpodq2p8aqpip-wheel- --pyt
hon-tag cp36:
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['d:\\softwares\\python3.6.1\\lib', 'C:\\', 'd
:\\softwares\\python3.6.1\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries openblas not found in ['d:\\softwares\\python3.6.1\\lib', 'C:\\',
'd:\\softwares\\python3.6.1\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  d:\softwares\python3.6.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1051
: UserWarning: Specified path C:\projects\numpy-wheels\windows-wheel-builder\atl
as-builds\atlas-3.10.1-sse2-32\lib is invalid.
    pre_dirs = system_info.get_paths(self, section, key)
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_info:
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_info:
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  d:\softwares\python3.6.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572:
 UserWarning:
      Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
      the ATLAS environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  lapack_info:
    libraries lapack not found in ['d:\\softwares\\python3.6.1\\lib', 'C:\\', 'd
:\\softwares\\python3.6.1\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  d:\softwares\python3.6.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572:
 UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  d:\softwares\python3.6.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572:
 UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
    NOT AVAILABLE

  Running from scipy source directory.
  non-existing path in 'scipy\\integrate': 'quadpack.h'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-k8_u1d9i\scipy\setup.py
", line 416, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-k8_u1d9i\scipy\setup.py
", line 412, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "d:\softwares\python3.6.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", l
ine 135, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-k8_u1d9i\scipy\setup.py
", line 336, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('scipy')
    File "d:\softwares\python3.6.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.p
y", line 1001, in add_subpackage
      caller_level = 2)
    File "d:\softwares\python3.6.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.p
y", line 970, in get_subpackage
      caller_level = caller_level + 1)
    File "d:\softwares\python3.6.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.p
y", line 907, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('linalg')
    File "d:\softwares\python3.6.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.p
y", line 1001, in add_subpackage
      caller_level = 2)
    File "d:\softwares\python3.6.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.p
y", line 970, in get_subpackage
      caller_level = caller_level + 1)
    File "d:\softwares\python3.6.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.p
y", line 907, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
      raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
  numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for scipy
  Running setup.py clean for scipy
  Complete output from command d:\softwares\python3.6.1\python.exe -u -c "import
 setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-b
uild-k8_u1d9i\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code
=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))"
 clean --all:

  `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:

    - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
    - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                        files that aren't checked into the git repo)

  Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).


  ----------------------------------------
  Failed cleaning build dir for scipy
Failed to build scipy
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    Complete output from command d:\softwares\python3.6.1\python.exe -u -c "impo
rt setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip
-build-k8_u1d9i\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);co
de=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec')
)" install --record C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-6p2n9krk-record\ins
tall-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['d:\\softwares\\python3.6.1\\lib', 'C:\\',
'd:\\softwares\\python3.6.1\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['d:\\softwares\\python3.6.1\\lib', 'C:\\'
, 'd:\\softwares\\python3.6.1\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    d:\softwares\python3.6.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:10
51: UserWarning: Specified path C:\projects\numpy-wheels\windows-wheel-builder\a
tlas-builds\atlas-3.10.1-sse2-32\lib is invalid.
      pre_dirs = system_info.get_paths(self, section, key)
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    d:\softwares\python3.6.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:57
2: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['d:\\softwares\\python3.6.1\\lib', 'C:\\',
'd:\\softwares\\python3.6.1\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    d:\softwares\python3.6.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:57
2: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    d:\softwares\python3.6.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:57
2: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    Running from scipy source directory.
    non-existing path in 'scipy\\integrate': 'quadpack.h'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-k8_u1d9i\scipy\setup.
py", line 416, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-k8_u1d9i\scipy\setup.
py", line 412, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "d:\softwares\python3.6.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py",
 line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-k8_u1d9i\scipy\setup.
py", line 336, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('scipy')
      File "d:\softwares\python3.6.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util
.py", line 1001, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "d:\softwares\python3.6.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util
.py", line 970, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "d:\softwares\python3.6.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util
.py", line 907, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('linalg')
      File "d:\softwares\python3.6.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util
.py", line 1001, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "d:\softwares\python3.6.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util
.py", line 970, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "d:\softwares\python3.6.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util
.py", line 907, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "d:\softwares\python3.6.1\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;
__file__='C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-k8_u1d9i\\scipy\\
setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\
n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\U
sers\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-6p2n9krk-record\install-record.txt --single
-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ADMI
NI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-k8_u1d9i\scipy\
```

Kindly help.
Thank you. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [install scipy on windows with easy\_install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583380/install-scipy-on-windows-with-easy-install)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use an unofficial installer for SciPy. 
[Here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) you can find the link with all unofficial installer, please search and open the scipy link in the list.

Keep in mind to choose the right version, in this way:

1. cp = python version (i.e. cp27 = Pythonv2.7)
2. win_amd64 = x86_64 or win32 = windows 32 bit

Download it and then install it with the following command

```
pip install --user <scipy.whl>
```

for example the following command install scipy v.0.19.0, for Python2.7 and for windowns 32:

```
pip install --user scipy‑0.19.0‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl
```

Comment: Glad to help you!